# Link from iOS app to website

Tags: ios

I am looking to link my iOS app to my website. I want the link to open the safari web browser. Currently the link goes to the website but stays in the app.

Here is what I am using:

```
<a   onclick="window.location.href='http://www.website.com/folder/page.php';">Contact</a>
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Your app has a `UIWebView` embedded, with the javascript code posted in your question, and when you click it goes to your website, but still in the `UIWebView`, and you want to switch to Safari instead?

Comment: I'm not sure it is possible from HTML/Javascript. I know there's a way to trigger native code from your web view (but don't remember the details), and that could work: from your native code, you can launch Safari and direct it to your URL..

Comment: You code snippet is in Javascript and HTML, not Objective C. Is your app using a cross platform framework (such as PhoneGap or Ionic)?

Comment: Yes the app is using a cross platform framework (such as PhoneGap or Ionic)

Comment: Do I need to erase window.location.

Comment: Please provide more info in your question - what product are you using? What specific behaviour do you want to accomplish?

Comment: @remus I am using Xcode. I want the users of the app to click the link for contact and the Safari web browser to open

Comment: Have a look at https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/SafariServices/Reference/SFSafariViewController_Ref/index.html

Comment: @user2512457 Not suggested to use "cross platform framework", and unclear what are you trying to achieve. Your goal is easier to be achieved using native languages.

Comment: @raptor How about this NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.stackoverflow.com"];

if (![[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url]) {
  NSLog(@"%@%@",@"Failed to open url:",[url description]);
} ?

Comment: What about [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.apple.com"]];

Answer (score 1):

To open a webpage in device's browse, use  following code

```
NSURL *strURL = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:@"http://www.website.com/folder/page.php"];
if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:strURL]) {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:strURL];
} else {
    NSLog(@"Cann't open url : %@",strURL);
}
```

Comment: Also be aware that on iOS 9 the URL will need to be white listed.

Comment: Yes, thats true. Apple have implemented security for urls.

Comment: @remus How can I adjust my font for my iOS app? This is what I am using but the font will not change in the app. <h1 style="font-size:14px !important;font-weight:bold;font-face:"AR CARTER"">

Comment: @user2512457 Objective-C is not HTML. You can't just use HTML and CSS to make it work.

Comment: @remus HTML is what I am typing into XCODE. The app was originally created using phone gap